# MySQL - creating an SQL Algorithm to determine random 'popular' content

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, codeigniter

I'm looking to create an SQL query (in MySQL) that will display 6 random, yet popular entries in my web application.

My database has the following tables:

- favorites
- submissions
- submissions_tags
- tags
- users

  1. `submissions_tags` and `tags` are cross-referencing tables that give each submission a certain number of tags.
  2. `submissions` contains boolean `featured`, int `downloads`, and int `views`, all three of which I'd like to use to weight this query with.
  3. The `favorites` table is again a cross-reference table with the fields `submission_id` and `user_id`. Counting the number of times each submission has been favorited would be good to weigh the results with.

So basically I want to select 6 random rows weighted with these four variables - `featured, downloads, views,` and `favorite count`. Each time the user refreshes the page, I want a new random 6 to be selected. So maybe the query could limit it to 12 most-recent but only pluck 6 random results out to show. Is that a sensible idea in terms of processing etc.?

**So my question is, how can I go about writing this query? Where should I begin?** I am using PHP/CodeIgniter to drive this site with. Is it possible to get the entire lot in one query, or will I have to use multiple queries to do this? Or, do I need to simplify my ideas?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented something similar to this before. The route I took was to have a script run on the server every XX minutes to fill a table with a pool of items (say 20-30 items). Then the query to use in your application would be randomly pick 5 or so from that table.

Just need to setup an algorithm to select those 20-30 items. @Emmerman's is similar to what I used before to calculate a `popularity_number` where I took weights of multiple associations to the item (`views`, `downloads`, etc) to get an overall number.  We also used an `age` to make sure the pool of items stayed up-to-date. You'll have to tinker with the algorithm over time to make sure the relevant items are being populated.

Comment: A good way to think about it, via Cron job... I will take a  look, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to calc some `popularity` which can be for e.g.

`popularity = featured*W1 + downloads*W2 + views*W3 + fcount*W4`

Where W1-W4 are constant weights.

Then add some random number to popularity and sort for it.

Comment: But you need to cache this or store somewhere, because this query will be too heavy.